# Multiple HTTP calls using RXJS inside of pipe operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

I have 3 API endpoints (candidates, vacancies and interviews).

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Serj"
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Alex"
        },
      ],
    "vacancies": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "title": "Java"
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "title": "JS"
        },
      ],
   "interviews": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "candidateId": 1,
           "vacancyId": 2,
           "date": "2018-12-11"
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "candidateId": 2,
           "vacancyId": 1,
           "date": "2018-12-11"
        },
      ]
}
```

First of I get interviews by date and and have an array of interviews.

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('date', '2018-12-11');
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/interviews', {params}).pipe();
```

And as I `subscribe()` to the output of the `pipe()` - I wanna get array of interviews where instead of `"candidateId"` and `"vacancyId"` are actual objects `candidate` and `vacancy` fetched from appropriate endpoints.

So result (`Interview[]`) should look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "candidate": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Serj"
    },
    "vacancy": {
      // vacancy instance
    },
    "date": "2018-12-11"
  },
  // second interview object
]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right, you want your interview response to be filtered out to contain an array of objects with fields candidateId and vacancyId only ?

If that would be the case, you can use this method:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/interviews', {params})
  .pipe(
     flatMap(item => item),
     map(({ candidates, vacancies, interviews}) => 
        interviews.map(({ id, candidateId, vacancyId, date }) => ({ 
           id,
           candidate: candidates.filter(c => c.id === candidateId)[0], 
           vacancy: vacancies.filter(v => v.id === vacancyId)[0],
           date
        })
     )),
     reduce((acc, val) => [acc, val])  
  )
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-rxjs) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just edited my question to be more precise what is expected as an output.

Comment: @EugeneChristo Had updated the Stackblitz demo in regards with the updated question. Just open the console and the result is there :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are very beautiful and kind :)

Comment: The last `reduce` could be written also as: `.reduce( _ => _ )` because _finally_ you just have _one element_ in the _outer array_. ie: `[[1,2]].reduce( _ => _ )` outputs: `[1, 2]` In your case, will be the _first_ and _second_ result's object.